# What is the relation between the union of the derived sets to the derived set of the union in a metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $A$ and $B$ be two (non-empty) subsets of $X$. Let $A^\prime$, $B^\prime$, and $(A \cup B)^\prime$ denote the derived set (i.e. the set of all the limit points) of $A$, $B$, and $A\cup B$, respectively. Then we can show that 
$$ A^\prime \cup B^\prime \subseteq (A \cup B)^\prime.$$ 
Can this inclusion be proper? If so, what example can we give? If not, how to prove the equality?

I know that in a topological space, the above inclusion can be proper. For example, Let $(X,\mathbb{\tau})$ be a topological space, where $$X \colon= \{a, b, c \}$$ and $$\mathbb{\tau} \colon= \left\{\emptyset, X, \{a,b\}, \{c\} \right\}. $$ Then if we let $$ A \colon= \{a,b\}$$ and $$B \colon= \{c\},$$ then we have $$A^\prime = \{a,b\}, $$ whereas $$B^\prime = \emptyset;$$ so $$A^\prime \cup B^\prime = \{a,b\}.$$ However, $$A \cup B = \{a,b,c\} $$ so that $$(A\cup B)^\prime = \{a,b,c\}.$$ Hence in this case $$A^\prime \cup B^\prime \subset (A \cup B)^\prime, $$ but $$A^\prime \cup B^\prime \neq (A \cup B)^\prime, $$

Comment: The equality $A' \cup B' = (A\cup B)'$ holds in all $T_1$-spaces, hence in metric spaces.

Comment: Daniel Fischer, could you please elaborate upon your comment? Is it only in $T_1$ spaces at the least that this equality holds? If so, then what about the answer posted by user87690? He hasn't made use of the $T_1$ axiom, you see?

Comment: I haven't looked at your example and took the assertion that the inclusion can be proper as true, without checking it. In your example, $c\notin (A\cup B)'$, since $\{c\}$ is a neighbourhood of $c$ not containing any other point of $X$. Indeed the equality holds in arbitrary topological spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x ∈ (A ∪ B)'$. Either $x ∈ A'$ or there exists $U_A$ neighborhood of $x$ such that $U ∩ A ⊆ \{x\}$. And the same for $B$. So either $x ∈ A' ∪ B'$ or $(U_A ∩ U_B) ∩ (A ∪ B) ⊆ \{x\}$, which is contradiction. So $(A ∪ B)' = A' ∪ B'$ holds for arbitrary topological space.

Comment: user87690, in the light of what you've demonstrated as proved, what's the flaw in my example? Don't you think that my example and your reasoning seem contradictory?

Comment: Well, what is the other point of $\{a, b, c\}$ which is intersected by $\{c\}$, which is a neighborhood of $c$?